# A form in the suggest list in Webix (protoUI)

Tags: javascript, popup, webix, suggestbox

I'm using Webix and trying to create my own suggest list via `protoUI`
Is it possible to attach the full-featured form (with the text field and the buttons) as a suggest list in Webix?
I've already create the UI-part, but I now can't add selected value to the textfield:

```
webix.protoUI({
  name:"suggest",
  $init:function(obj){
    obj.body = {
      view:"layout",
      rows: [{
        view:"list",
        width:300,
        data:["a-b-c", "d-e-f", "g-h-i"],
        autoheight:true,
        select:true,
      },
      { view: "text" },
      { view: "button", value: "Add", width:100, align:"center" },
            ]
    };
  },
}, webix.ui.suggest);
```

Here's the [snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/55006a3d) of my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default popup contains only one sub-view (a list from which you choose the value). You need to redefine getList function, and only then you'll get the values:

```
getList:function(){
    return this.getBody().getChildViews()[0];
}
```

Your snippet:   http://webix.com/snippet/cfba579c